# Navigate up from activity back to fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-navigation

Let's say I have two activities called `A_Activity` and `B_Activity`. `A_Activity` has 3 fragments named `A_Fragment`, `B_Fragment`, and `C_Fragment`. `A_Activity` acts as a base activity for the three fragments.

From `B_Fragment`, it is possible to navigate to `B_Activity` and from `B_Activity`it is possible to navigate up to `B_Fragment`. from `A_Activity` it is possible to navigate to `A_Fragment`, `B_Fragment`, or`C_Fragment`. Lastly, from `A_Fragment`, `B_Fragment`, or `C_Fragment`, it is possible to navigate to any other fragment.

Here's an arbitrary representation of the hierarchy of activities and their respective fragments:

```
A_Activity
    A_Fragment
    B_Fragment
        B_Activity
    C_Fragment
```

Let it also be a given that `A_Fragment` is the default fragment for `A_Activity`.

My current solution to this is: in `B_Activity`'s home icon selected, I am creating a new intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B_Activity.this, A_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("data_to_start_B_Fragment", "B"); // instead of starting A Fragment
startActivity(intent);
```

**What is the proper way to navigate to `B_Fragment` from `B_Activity`?**

Comment: Is there a reason that B_Activity must be an Activity? Can you implement it as just another Fragment instead?

Comment: @Code-Guru Each of the fragments represents a navigation drawer item whereas `B_Activity` is just a different clickable link from `B_Fragment`. I'm not really sure though, but I think it makes more sense for it to be an activity.

Answer (score 1):

From `B_Fragment`, starting `B_Activity` using `startActivityForResult(...)` by `getApplicationcontext` not `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.

In `Activity B,` you use `setResult(data here)` to return fragment and finish `ActivityB` to back `fragment B`.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but `B_Activity` might have sub-activities and sub-fragments of its own.

Comment: B_Activity have one sub class is B_Fragment. B_Fragment have sub class is A_Activity. If do that, A_activity isn't sub of B_Activity. Other clean ways is startActivityB from ActivityA, then setResult with data from activityB for ActivityA, ActivityA transfer all data received for FragmentB.

Answer (score 0):

From B_Activity to B_Fragment (if you start B_Activity from B_Fragment), you just need to detect action from either home button or system back button and then kill the Activity by calling

```
finish()
```

e.g. in B_Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```